# Can't access Adonis from Docker Container

Tags: javascript, docker, adonis.js

I use Docker to contain my Adonis app. The build was success but when I access the app, I got `ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED` or `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

My docker compose contains adonis and database. Previously, I use the setup similar with this for my expressjs app, and it has no problem.

The adonis .env is remain standard, modification.

This is my setup:

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3'
services:
  adonis:
    build: ./adonis
    volumes:
      - ./adonis/app:/usr/src/app
    networks:
      - backend
    links:
      - database
    ports:
      - "3333:3333"
  
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 33060:3306
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: "user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "root"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"

  networks:
    backend:
      driver: bridge
```

```
# adonis/Dockerfile

FROM node:12-alpine

RUN npm i -g @adonisjs/cli

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./app/. .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3333

CMD ["adonis", "serve", "--dev"]
```

I couldn't spot anything wrong with my setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The serve command starts the HTTP server on the port defined inside the `.env` file in the project root.

You should have something like this(note that `HOST` has to be set to `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` to accept connections from the outside):

```
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=3333
APP_URL=http://${HOST}:${PORT}
```

Comment: I'm glad it did. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Thank you so much. I was pulling out my hair for over a day wondering why this didn't work.